# Cancer Life Expectancy

Tags: cancer, life-expectancy, healthcare-data

I understand there is data for 5/10 year survival rates for different cancers. Is there any data on survival rates for survivors? IE what is the patient's 5 year survival rate, given no recurrence in 8 years?

Comment: this varies by cancer. In many, if you haven't died after 5 years you likely aren't going to. In others, people continue to die even 5 years after diagnosis. Which cancer are you interested in?

Comment: Generally survival rates take "survivors" into account with the #-year estimates, so a 10-year estimate would include those who had 8-year remission.  But with a specific cancer a more specific answer could be given.

Comment: Breast cancer. So a close family member has been clear for 5 years.